# Is there any way to fix the order of COM struct members when importing to C#?

Tags: c#, c++, com, com-interop, idl

I defined a struct in .idl file of C++ project, and the struct contained one VARIANT member.

```
[uuid(C42A456C-C139-4339-A023-F9458C8A7386)]
struct TEST_STRUCT
{

    int                 Type;
    VARIANT             DateTime;
    float               Result;
};
```

The interface is:

```
[id(1), helpstring("Test1")] HRESULT Test1([in] int nID, [out, retval] SAFEARRAY(struct TEST_STRUCT)* ppVal);
```

**Then I imported this struct into C# project via "Add Reference", but the member order was changed. It looks like this:**

```
namespace ASLib
{    
    [Guid("C42A456C-C139-4339-A023-F9458C8A7386")]
    public struct TEST_STRUCT
    {
        public object DateTime;
        public int Type;
        public float Result;
    }
}
```

**The order of DateTime member was changed to first in C#, it caused an Interop.COMException "Bad variable type" when C# calls that interface.**

So is there any way to fix the order of struct members in COM idl file? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is very strange, never heard of this going wrong before.  Where did you get the converted declaration from?  Also try running Tlbimp.exe instead of relying on Add Reference.  A workaround is to decompile the import library with ildasm.exe, alter the IL and compile again with ilasm.exe

Comment: Yes, it's very strange. I didn't meet this issue before. The converted declaration is in the metadata which is opened by selecting "Go To Definition" in the right menu. I'll try the workaround way later, and then let you know the result. Thanks a lot. BTW, do you hear any property instruction of IDL to fix the memory layout?

Comment: There aren't any.  The point of IDL is to nail this down.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the struct layout by hand via [StructLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Add the `FieldOffset` attribute to the generated fields.

It'll probably be something like:

```
public struct TEST_STRUCT
{
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public object DateTime;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int Type;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public float Result;
}
```

Comment: We have to redefine the struct in C# if using your approach.(Specified the StructLayout) It'll generate many redundant code. I just want to know how to fix the memory layout in C++ idl.